# Plotting Previous day high and low (Pinescript)

Tags: pine-script

Just learned to plot previous day high and low. And it plotted fine for the completed sessions but it keeps on plotting for every candle's high and low (for current session). I find it distracting.I use 5 min chart.  Code (v4):

```
1. // Previous day high low
 2. plotDHL = input(title="Plot PDH PDL", type=input.bool, defval=true)
 3. pdh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
 4. pdl = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)
 5. cDHL = color.new(#f21bf2, 40)
 6. plot(series=plotDHL ? pdh : 0, title = "PDH", style = myStyle, linewidth = 1, color = cDHL)
 7. plot(series=plotDHL ? pdl : 0, title = "PDL", style = myStyle, linewidth = 1, color = cDHL)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if my answer will be practical, but you can use :

```
a = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
b = 0.
b := barstate.islast ? b[1] : a
```

Comment: sorry how do I use that

Answer (score 0):

last day high with no repaint :

```
Last_D_High= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
```

last day low with no repaint :

```
Last_D_Low= request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low[barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
```